# multithreading in C using -lpthread

Tags: c, multithreading

So I designed a server to accept multiple clients in real time where the clients will 'speak' and the server will 'repeat' it. The clients will remain active constantly until I quit it. I tried implementing this using the -lpthread but the server will accept all the client connections, but then ignore all commands received except from the first client. Here is what I tried so far:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    pthread_t client_thread;
    pthread_attr_t attr;
... 
while(1) {  /* main accept() loop */


    sin_size = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    if ((new_fd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&their_addr, \
    &sin_size)) == -1) {
        perror("accept");
        continue;
    }
    printf("server: got connection from %s\n", \
        inet_ntoa(their_addr.sin_addr));

    pthread_attr_t attr;
    pthread_attr_init(&attr);

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_CLIENTS; i++) {
        pthread_create(&client_thread, &attr, decider, new_fd);
        pthread_join(client_thread,NULL);
    }
...
```

Currently, the only options I can choose between are multithreading or thread pooling. Thanks.

Comment: `pthread_join()` blocks until the specified thread terminates.  That's its whole point.  By having the main thread join the new thread immediately after creating it, you ensure that only one client thread runs at a time.  Also, you will eventually exhaust the server's queue of pending connections if enough clients try to connect.

Comment: The two calls `pthread_create` and `pthread_join` one right after another guarantee you will only run **one thread at a time**. Is that what you want?

Comment: Nop, I removed it but the same problem still happens. The server just say received connection both but the same problem still happens. Beyond the first, all gets ignored.

Comment: Why are you looping: 'for (int i = 0; i < MAX_CLIENTS; i++) {'  ??

Comment: BTW, if you GCC implementation provides the option `-pthread` use it instead of just `-lpthread`.

Answer (score 3):

You call `pthread_create` and then immediately `pthread_join`.

The problem with that is that `pthread_join` will *wait* for the thread to exit, making your code serial instead of parallel.

If you want to dynamically create a thread when you receive a connection, then create *one* thread. Don't create `MAX_CLIENT` threads in a loop, where *all* threads handle the very same connection.

---

If you want to use a thread-pool, then create all threads *first* before the "main accept() loop", and simply have them do nothing (to begin with). Then use a (protected) queue where you add new connections, and the threads check this queue for new connections, and the one thread that doesn't already handle a connection will pick it up and process it.

In pseudo-code, something like this:

```
thread_function()
{
    while (true)
    {
        sleep_while_queue_is_empty();
        get_descriptor_from_queue();

        handle_connection();
    }
}
```

Comment: "*You call `pthread_create` and then immediately `pthread_join`.*" I really wonder why this seem to be such a common mistake ...

Comment: @MartinJames: You want to say it's copypasta?